# save currencies to pandas store with precision (as Decimal?)

Tags: python, pandas, pytables

In pandas I work a lot with currencies. Up to this point I've been using the default floats, but dealing with the lack of precision is annoying and error prone. I'm trying to switch over to using `Decimal` for some pieces, which while it likely makes calculations a lot slower, is precise. However when I try to save to a pandas store (e.g. hdf5store via pytables) I get:
`TypeError: Cannot serialize the column [o] because its data contents are [mixed] object dtype`

Here's a short sample of what I'm trying to do:

```
import pandas as pd
from decimal import Decimal
teststore = pd.HDFStore('teststore.h5')
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'o':[Decimal('5.1')]})
teststore['test'] = df
```

.. which raises the exception above. `df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)` doesn't help.

Is there a way to save Decimal to a pandas store, and if not, is there a recommended way of precisely storing currencies in a pandas store?

I'm using python 2.7.8, pandas 0.14.1, and pytables 3.1.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works on 0.15.0. Though it is essentially pickled as its an actual python object, so you get almost no benefit from using HDF5.

```
In [46]: from decimal import Decimal

In [47]: teststore = pd.HDFStore('teststore.h5')

In [48]: df = pd.DataFrame(data={'o':[Decimal('5.1')]})

In [49]: teststore['test'] = df
pandas/io/pytables.py:2487: PerformanceWarning: 
your performance may suffer as PyTables will pickle object types that it cannot
map directly to c-types [inferred_type->mixed,key->block0_values] [items->['o']]

  warnings.warn(ws, PerformanceWarning)
```

As an FYI, generally float64 has 14-16 digits of precision, so not sure why you are not using them (you may need to change the display printing precision to see it).

```
In [50]: In [34]: pd.set_option('precision',16)

In [51]: In [35]: s = Series([0.0000000000001,0.000000000000002])

In [52]: s+s
Out[52]: 
0    0.000000000000200
1    0.000000000000004
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Very cool that it works in 0.15.0 and performance warning heeded.

Comment: re np.float64 vs decimal: I don't need such levels of precision - typically at most I need down to 0.0001. For example if I start with 0 and add 1 cent (0.01) ten times, resulting in 10 cents (0.1), the result is different from directly specifying 0.1. I end up having to build and use a small library of "soft" comparators etc that allow for a small amount of error, which are slower and a hassle to use. There are many threads about this on SO and elsewhere and the recommended solution typically seems to be Decimal, although I haven't found anything numpy/pandas specific.